# Can't change normals even after rotating it

Tags: normals

[image] I wasn't able to edit my normals on my textured meshes, but it only works on the newly added meshes. Is there a reason why it did that?

Comment: could you please share the mesh that has the problem? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some modifiers like subsurf, they can overwrite normals, you can check *Use custom normals* in *Advanced* section:

[image]